# How to revert to old Swift's AnyObject & Any auto-convert behavior?

Tags: swift, xcode

I understand that Swift wants to enforce strong typing by removing the auto-converting behavior of any type into `AnyObject` and `Any`. But sometimes, for some kind of parameter, I just want to actually declare that the parameter accepts *anything* without the need to add `as AnyObject` or `as Any` because for my situation it made the code ugly as hell and very unnecessary because I do check for various types of data from that parameter inside the function. How can I evoke that behavior (locally or globally) in the new Swift 3.x or 4.x?

Comment: Why don't you use generics for those special cases?

Comment: @Lawliet what do you mean by "generics" ?

Answer (score 0):

As of this [SE-0072](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md) evolution proposal of swift, you might not be able to do that in `Swift 3`. There are some conversion issues of which are described in short [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md#motivation).

For this the [Proposed solution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md#proposed-solution) states that ***"Implicit bridging conversions in Swift 3 should be eliminated".***

And from [Impact on existing code](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md#impact-on-existing-code) it is stated:

> Code that previously relied on implicit conversions between Swift value types and their associated bridged Objective-C type will now require a manual coercion via an `as` cast.